# Two Xeon Processors with Different Clock Speeds on the Same Motherboard: Possible?

Tags: central-processing-unit, multi-core, xeon

If I have a 2.0gHz Woodcrest 5130 Xeon and a 1.6gHz Woodcrest 5110 Xeon, can I put them both on the same motherboard?

The machine in question is a PowerEdge 2950.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bad idea, not the worst, that was Britney Spear's shaven head, but not far off.

Seriously though, terrible idea - most mobos won't even try to start the second processor, some not even the first one.

Answer (score 1):

5110 has FSB 1066mhz while 5130 1333mhz so in this case - not possible. What about the same FSB/voltage, I don't know but I would never try :)